# Insufficient permissions to save file on Visual studio code with docker desktop

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, permissions

I am having insufficient permissions issues from visual studio code when I save a file in my apache container inside of docker desktop.

My setup is the following:

- Installed docker desktop and using WSL 2, with the Debian distribution
- I created differente containers (for magento 2)
- I can access the files in the windows browser directory by typin in \wsl$, this will open for example \wsl.localhost\Debian\var\www\projects\magento\magentostore\src folder

In Visual Studio Code I open this path \wsl.localhost\Debian\var\www\projects\magento\magentostore\src , and if I modify and save a file i get the following errors :

```
Failed to save 'bootstrap.php': Insufficient permissions. Select 'Retry as Admin' to retry as administrator.
```

If I 'Retry as Admin' I get

```
Failed to save 'bootstrap.php': Command failed: "C:\Users\dan\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin\code.cmd" --file-write "c:\Users\dan\AppData\Roaming\Code\code-elevated-60PHGFW0" "\\wsl.localhost\Debian\var\www\projects\magento\magentostore\src\app\bootstrap.php"
Error using --file-write: EPERM: operation not permitted, open '\\wsl.localhost\Debian\var\www\projects\magento\magentostore\src\app\bootstrap.php'
```

It's a permission issue but I am not sure what to do

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer,for some reason in the apache container,the owner of the project is "root" but visual studio code is another user called "application".

I notice it because I could not modify files in studio code that were not created by visual studio code,but I was able to create new files,those I could manipulate.

So basically I changed the owner of the entire project to "application".

You can also do `chmod 777 -R <directory>` but I think this is bad practice.